# Update existing base.html path without modifying all the paths

Tags: django

I need to update the path for mezzanine in django. Is there a way to update `{% extends "base.html" %}` to `{% extends "index/base.html" %}` without changing all the files that include the `extends`?

Comment: Global "Find All and Replace"?
It's supported by majority of good editors.

Comment: i dont want to do that.. because im modifying module headers. what if i missed one?